# Extract value from response that is JSON

Tags: java, rest-assured

Below is a JSON response from a GET API call

```
[{
    "_id": "60df3ffd440138383acb62cb",
    "sequence": 2412,
    "kit_config_id": {
        "_id": "60df3ffd440138383acb62c6",
        "kitDetails": [{
                "_id": "60df3ffd440138383acb62ca"
            },
            {

                "_id": "60df3ffd440138383acb62c9"

            }

        ]

    }
}]
```

I want to fetch the value of this `_id` "60df3ffd440138383acb62c9" that is inside the `kitDetails`.

Comment: you can look at how `JsonObject` works in java. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html

Comment: @prashantpiyush I want to fetch the value using Restassured, please help me with that

Comment: you can try `JsonPath` https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath

Comment: Can you please provide exact answer, as I am new to Restassured , Jsonobject and jsonpath

Comment: Go through this once https://devqa.io/parse-json-response-rest-assured/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this is what you are looking for

```
List<Map<String,Object>> data = new JsonPath(json).getList("$");
    Map<String,Object> kitConfigId = (Map<String, Object>) data.get(0).get("kit_config_id");
    List<Map<String,Object>> kitDetails = (List<Map<String, Object>>) kitConfigId.get("kitDetails");
    for (Map<String, Object> kitDetail : kitDetails) {
        System.out.println(kitDetail.get("_id").toString());
    }

//60df3ffd440138383acb62ca
//60df3ffd440138383acb62c9
```